# I am trying to do a Month Over Month review but not all months have data and the users want placeholders for the months with no data

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, grouping

I am trying to do a Month Over Month review but not all months have data and the users want placeholders for the months with no data. I was trying to use my start and end date parameters but I am not getting anywhere.

I am using SSRS - attempting to use a matrix to show on the left hand side for the rows the Month and the column grouped by current year and prior year which is generated from my date parameters. I have four date parameters; a current year star, current year end, prior year start and prior year end.

I can get the matrix to populate if the prior year has data for a month that the current year does not and vice versa but I cannot get the data to populate with a placeholder for a month with no data.

Has anyone had success doing this without using a CTE?

Comment: If you don't already have a dates table in your database, create one. There are lots of examples on how to generate one easily. Once you have your dates table use that as the primary table and `LEFT JOIN` your data to it, that way you will always have all dates/months present

Comment: @AlanSchofield that did it. I had seen temp tables with a calendar (my DB source is a vendor DB and they don't have a Calendar Table and so I cannot create one in the database) but I could not figure out how to join it to my query. I managed to get it done this afternoon. Thanks